# How to I capture an argument sent to a mock?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ocmock

Does anyone know how to capture an argument sent to an OCMock object?

```
id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:someClass]
NSObject* captureThisArgument;
[[mock expect] foo:<captureThisArgument>]

[mock foo:someThing]
GHAssertEquals[captured, someThing, nil];
```

How do I go about validating the argument to foo? I'm happy to do it within a block in the mock definition too, but if I could get the object out so that I can assert on feature of it later that would be brilliant.

Is this possible with OCMock?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to validate your parameter maybe you can do it directly while you are setting your stub with something like :

```
id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:someClass];
NSObject* captureThisArgument;
[[mock expect] foo:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^(id value){ 
    // Capture argument here...
}]];
```

Regards,
Quentin A

Comment: I like this. It's similar to how I would go about mocking with a hancrest matcher in groovy. Thanks :).

Answer (score 4):

You can stub the call and pass it to a block that verifies it:

```
NSObject *expected = ...;

id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:someClass]
void (^theBlock)(NSInvocation *) = ^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    NSObject *actual;
    [invocation getArgument:&actual atIndex:2];
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);   
};
[[[mock stub] andDo:theBlock] foo:[OCMArg any]];

[mock foo:expected];
```

There's also a callback version of this, but the control flow gets more complex, as you need a state variable that's visible to both your test and the verification callback:

```
[[[mock stub] andCall:@selector(aMethod:) onObject:anObject] someMethod:someArgument]
```

Comment: Thanks. @Quentin's answer was the concise one I was hoping for, but I really appreciate your example too. It's good to have an example of how to validate multiple arguments at mocking time. (I'd throw assertions in theBlock if anything wasn't right).

Comment: The first two arguments of an NSInvocation are reserved for self and _cmd; the "first" argument to a method is at index 2.