# capture multiple arguments in unit test

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am using [OCMock 3](http://ocmock.org/reference/) to do unit testing. I have a very simple function named `processInfo` to test:

```
@implementation MyService
// in my test case, I want to test this function
-(void) processInfo{
  ...
  [self handleDataWith:infoData name:someName];
}

-(void) handleDataWith:(NSData*)data name:(NSString*)name{
  ...
}
```

My test case is supposed to be something like this to capture argument (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292551/how-to-i-capture-an-argument-sent-to-a-mock)):

```
-(void) testProcessInfo {
  id serviceMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[MyService class]];
  // Wow!Wow! wait, the answer I linked above only talk about how to capture a single argument, 
  //BUT I have two arguments to capture, how to do then?
  OCMExpect([serviceMock handleDataWith:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^(id value){ 
    // Capture argument here...but what about several arguments?
}]]);
```

The answer I linked above tells how to use `[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^(id value)]` to capture a single argument, but I want to capture two arguments. How to do it then?

In general, I can hardly find a well documented way on internet about how to **capture multiple arguments** in unit test with **OCMock v3**. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment to the answer to one of your other questions ([Check argument value passed into function in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706307/check-argument-value-passed-into-function-in-unit-test)), you have to use `andDo`.